# short html/css syntax: <div a b c></div> - any reasons why not?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I would like to discuss the way how I currently like to write html in cases when standard compliant syntax and semantics are not so important, like in a phonegap app (my principle then: if it works on all devices it's OK)

I make my html as short as possible in the following way:

```
<i x y z="0"><b a b c></b></i>
```

with css:

```
[x]{something}
[y]{something}
[z="0"]{...}
...
```

So this is instead of the normal class syntax which is to devious for my liking.

the pros for me:

- it's short and requires less time to type code
- combined with javascript it works nice to for instance toggle attribute values and then make styling dependent on the values
- I guess the html is faster to process by the machine because it's shorter but I'm not sure about css, maybe css classes are processed much faster than custom attributes? < please comment
- haven't found a case where it doesn't work

I would like to know whether there are any good reasons not to do this from a performance/technical perspective. But not from a 'code must be readable' perspective.

Comment: _"I guess it's faster to process by the machine because it's shorter"_ Well, that is often wrong. The `if/else` shorthand, for example, is slower than the longer version on most browsers: `var x = condition ? y : z;` vs `var x; if(condition){ x = y; } else { x = z; }`. Anyway, your question is opinion-based, and has nothing to do on this site.

Comment: Why can't a question about programming style be on this site, i think it's good for everyone to evaluate their way of coding. And the question is not opinion based because there might be performance issues with this style of coding that i'm not aware of. In fact that is my main question, I see you read the word 'opinion' in my question which I will now remove to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML spec doesn't say what the browser should do if it encounters an invalid attribute. At worst the only thing that'll happen is your code will fail validation.

> I guess the html is faster to process by the machine because it's shorter

Code that fights the spec/parser will almost invariably be slower than code that doesn't. This is because browser developers have to write special handling for non-conforming code since HTML is intended to be backwards compatible all the way to the very beginning. Saying "it's faster" because you shaved off a few bytes on an attribute name is a unfounded statement and bound to get you a room full of laughter in a code review.

Comment: that was the kind of answer i was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 1):

> when standard compliant syntax and semantics are not so important, like in a phonegap app

And what about if phonegap gets an update breaking your code because your are not standard conform?

> it's short and requires less time to type code

In the beginning it might be, but it decreases maintainability drastically. So if you need to change something after a while, coding will become really slow, because you will have problems understanding your own code.

> I guess the html is faster to process by the machine because it's shorter but I'm not sure about css, maybe css classes are processed much faster than custom attributes?

There won't be a noticeable difference for parsing.

A good coding style is a style that will allow you to add another person to your team and the effort to understand your code is as low as possible.